# showing undefined index while passing variable through url in php

Tags: php, html

```js
//passing value through url   
while($rowcontent=mysqli_fetch_array($details))
{
    echo "<tr><td><a href=http://localhost/study/study2/edit.php?toedit=$rowcontent[rollnumber]>edit</a></td><tr>";
}
```

```js
//receiving value from url
<html>
<form method="GET" action="edit.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">Enter Name <br>
    <input type="text" name="rollnumber" required>Enter Rollnumber <br>
    <input type="text" name="mark">Enter Mark  <br>
    <input type="text" name="dept">Enter Department <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> <br>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$rollnumber=$_GET["toedit"];
echo $rollnumber;
if(isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
    $name=$_GET["name"];
    $nrollnumber=$_GET["rollnumber"];
    $mark=$_GET["mark"];
    $department=$_GET["dept"];
    $connect=mysqli_connect("","root","","details");
    mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name'          rollnumber='$nrollnumber' mark='$mark' department='$department' WHERE rollnumber='$rollnumber'");
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

?>

above are two parts of code, where im trying to edit values in a DB by passing value (a roll number) through url but in editing code the value is not being received correctly or some other problem i cant figure out. i did the same for deleting a value from url but it seems to work.

Comment: $rollnumber is empty.

Comment: `rollnumber='$nrollnumber'` you sure this is correct?

Comment: Try setting the "Associative" flag in mysql fetch........mysqi_fetch_array($details, MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Comment: have you tried the variable in double quotes and possibly even escaping the dollar char?  This doesnt seem correct use of the code. you dont need to pass variable names normally, and you sure shouldnt pass the $ symbol.

Comment: im setting value for $nrollnumber  using $_GET["rollnumber"] from form. i didnt post the  detailed code.  @ muthafury

Comment: And are you sure your looking for a get variable and not a POST variable?  try this `<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
    if($_GET['toedit']){
  $rollnumber = $_GET['toedit'];
                var_dump($rollnumber);
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_GET);
  echo '</pre>';
 }

}`  or change to POST if not maybe? `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`  Edited just now..

Comment: im using GET @ brian

Comment: ok, did you try that code?  can you paste what it yields, back into your OP please?  (which ever var_dump happens).  And if you still get teh same undefined, change it to this.   

`<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
    echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($_GET['toedit']);
   echo '</pre>';
}`  

Edit: and if your using @get, then we should be seing a variable on the url that says &submit, but im not seeing a url query for the submit action, so your saying your not posting it from a form, then how is it being submitted?

Comment: so if thats the case `$_GET['submit']` the index 'submit' is missing is your undefined , lol.

You can try this instead if thats the case `if(isset($_GET["submit"])) { \\blah blah } else { echo 'oops, there is no submit index'; }`  DOnt forget about the else's, its part of error handling.

Comment: Do one thing `print_r($_GET); die;` and let me know, what it returns.

Comment: Notice:  Undefined index: toedit in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\study2\edit.php on line 12

NULL


Notice: Undefined index: toedit in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\study2\edit.php on line 14     @brian

Comment: output after using print_r()      Array ( [name] => xyz [rollnumber] => 15 [mark] => 88 [dept] => mca [submit] => submit ) my form inputs

Comment: which array did you print though?  print_r(what?) this is your $_GET right?  notice there is no 'toedit' there.  this might be your problem.

Comment: yes...but 'toedit' is being passed from url . cant get whats the problem .

Comment: Replace this line `echo "<tr><td><a href=http://localhost/study/study2/edit.php?toedit=$rowcontent[rollnumber]>edit</a></td><tr>";` with `echo "<tr><td><a href=http://localhost/study/study2/edit.php?toedit=".$rowcontent[rollnumber].">edit</a></td><tr>";`, then check and let me know.

Comment: same result no change

Comment: Write `$rollnumber=$_GET["toedit"];` before `if` and then do like `echo $rollnumber; die();` check what it return.

Comment: ya ..its returning me the correct result i wanted.

Comment: so after calling the page again after submitting the value is being removed.

Comment: Can you please add your whole code in your question above?

Comment: actually got my problem . im sending the rollnumber value to the edit.php (through url) page , after which i gives the form inputs and submits  at this point the value of 'to edit' is gone. is there any ways to hold the value.

Comment: You can use `<input type="hidden" value="" />` like this so this is hold the value on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
//receiving value from url
<html>
<form method="GET" action="edit.php">
    <?php
    while($rowcontent=mysqli_fetch_array($details))
    {
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="toedit" value="<?php echo $rowcontent[rollnumber]; ?>" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="name">Enter Name <br>
    <input type="text" name="rollnumber" required>Enter Rollnumber <br>
    <input type="text" name="mark">Enter Mark  <br>
    <input type="text" name="dept">Enter Department <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> <br>
</form>
```

inside **edit.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
    $name=$_GET["name"];
    $nrollnumber=$_GET["rollnumber"];
    $mark=$_GET["mark"];
    $department=$_GET["dept"];
    $connect=mysqli_connect("","root","","details");
    mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name' rollnumber='$nrollnumber' mark='$mark' department='$department' WHERE rollnumber='$rollnumber'");
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Comment: mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name' rollnumber='$nrollnumber' mark='$mark' department='$department' WHERE rollnumber='$rollnumber'");      is there any quotes rule violation because though now im receiving value correctly DB is not being updated.

Comment: You can use like `mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name' rollnumber='{$nrollnumber}' mark='{$mark}' department='{$department}' WHERE rollnumber='{$rollnumber}'");` or `mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='".name."' rollnumber='".$nrollnumber."' mark='".$mark."' department='".$department."' WHERE rollnumber='".$rollnumber."'");`

Comment: @bangBang Ok, good. By the way I'm female :P And you can accept my answer and do +vote it. If it is helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry typod the name wrong:
@bang Bang, if possible, would you mind marking it as accepted answer so the community can benefit, if this answer was acceptable from you?  Kind Regards.

Comment: @bangBang Ok, good. By the way I'm female :P And you can accept my answer and do +vote it. If it is helpful to you.